# Acessar prop em método com VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Estou passando um `array` de objetos para um componente e dentro deste componente eu tento acessar os valores passados:

```
<orders-list :orders="items"></orders-list>
```

Componente `orders-list:`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select
      v-model="filterChannel"
      :options="Array.from(
        new Set(
          orders.map(item => item.channel)
        )
      )"></b-form-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['orders'],
        ...
        created(){ console.log(this.orders); } // null
    }
</script>
```

dentro do `template` eu consigo renderizar todas as informações mas o console sempre me manda um erro dizendo que não pode acessar o método `map` de `null` mesmo renderizando os itens...
Já dentro do método é exibido `null`, porém se eu usar apenas `console.log(this)` eu consigo visualizar o `orders` com todos os pedidos dentro.

Como posso acessar um `prop` dentro dos métodos de um componente?

Comment: Estás a receber essas orders (items) como? Com um pedido ajax?

Comment: @Miguel, sim os pedidos vem do componente `pai` do `orders-list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acessas a um prop exatamente como estás fazer, `this.orders`, ex:

```
...
methods: {
    get_orders: function() {
        return this.orders;
    }
},
...
```

Como por comentário percebi que esses `items` vinham de um pedido ajax, que é assíncrono e ainda não foi completado aquando a renderização do componente, diria que a solução mais acertada será:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select v-if="orders != null"
      v-model="filterChannel"
      :options="Array.from(
        new Set(
          orders.map(item => item.channel)
        )
      )"></b-form-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['orders'],
        ...
        created(){ console.log(this.orders); } // null
    }
</script>
```

Nota que acrescentei  `v-if="orders != null"` de maneira a que esse elemento (`b-form-select`) só seja renderizado quando `orders` deixarem de ser `null`.

[DOCS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Também podes iniciar `items` como sendo um array vazio e assim escusas de colocar a condição que propus em cima, no componente pai podes:

```
<template>
    ...
    <orders-list :orders="items"></orders-list>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: [],
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: mesmo depois do componente montando se eu tentar acessar a `prop` por um `watcher` recebo undefined;

Comment: Mas ontem era null certo? @RFL, esse problema não tem a ver com o mesmo acho

Comment: vou abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: ok @RFL, vou ver se consigo ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Você pode atribuir o valor da prop como valor inicial de um campo qualquer e usa-lo depois como quiser.
Ex.:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ campoQualquer }}
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['orders'],
        data: function() {
            return {
                campoQualquer: this.orders
            }
        },
        methods: {
            umMetodoQualquer() {
                //faz o que quizer aqui
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```