# Acessar prop através de watchers em VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Um problema parecido foi resolvido nesta questão:

[Acessar prop em método com VueJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269269/acessar-prop-em-m%C3%A9todo-com-vuejs/269271?noredirect=1#comment552277_269271)

Onde uma `prop` era `null` pois a requisição `ajax` do componente pai ainda não havia concluido; porém no meu caso a `prop` é `undefined` mesmo após a montagem completa do componente e a passagem de dados via ajax ser concluída.

```
export default {
    props: ['orders'],
    filterID: null,
...
watch: {
    filterID: (value) => {
        console.log(this.orders) // undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: @Miguel eu preciso aplicar um filtro nas `orders` de acordo com o `ID` entao preciso capturar quando o campo `ID` é alterado.

Comment: o filtro seria aplicado onde está declado o `console.log` com: `this.orders.filter()...`

Comment: @Miguel coloquei um `watcher` em `orders` para "copiar" os dados para outra propriedade do componente mas sempre me retorna `null` mesmo depois dos dados serem passados para o componente de listagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá um valor *default* a essa `orders`(presumo que seja do tipo *array*) e assim quando o valor mudar o Vue, por reactividade vai atualizar o código que depende dele.

Assim em vêz de

```
props: ['orders'],
```

usa

```
props: {
    orders: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => ([])
    }
}
```

E assim já podes usar `filters`, `computed` ou no template diretamente que ele vai ser atualizado.